# Bootstrap Create a horizontal list of buttons, evenly spaced

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I create a horizontal list of buttons that are evenly spaced and evenly sized?

Essentially, the "navbar" has to span 85% of the entire screen page. Within the navbar, the five buttons have to fill the entire space and the spacing between them should be equal.

Finally, I'd like to have them stack vertically if the screen size gets to be less than 786 pixels wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox can do that:

```css
nav {
  width: 85%;
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
a {
  flex: 0 0 18%;
  /* any width as long a % times number of items does not exceed 100% */
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #000;
  color: white;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">Menu Item</a>
  <a href="#">Menu Item</a>
  <a href="#">Menu Item</a>
  <a href="#">Menu Item</a>
  <a href="#">Menu Item</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope [this one](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/justified-nav/#) is what you are trying to achieve.

HTML

```
    <nav>

              <ul class="nav nav-justified">

                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>

                <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>

                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>

                <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>

                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>

                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

              </ul>

</nav>
```

CSS

```
.nav-justified {

  background-color: #eee;

  border: 1px solid #ccc;

  border-radius: 5px;

}

.nav-justified > li > a {

  padding-top: 15px;

  padding-bottom: 15px;

  margin-bottom: 0;

  font-weight: bold;

  color: #777;

  text-align: center;

  background-color: #e5e5e5; /* Old browsers */

  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f5f5f5), to(#e5e5e5));

  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5 0%, #e5e5e5 100%);

  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5 0%, #e5e5e5 100%);

  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f5f5f5 0%,#e5e5e5 100%);

  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f5f5f5', endColorstr='#e5e5e5',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

  background-repeat: repeat-x; /* Repeat the gradient */

  border-bottom: 1px solid #d5d5d5;

}

.nav-justified > .active > a,

.nav-justified > .active > a:hover,

.nav-justified > .active > a:focus {

  background-color: #ddd;

  background-image: none;

  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.15);

          box-shadow: inset 0 3px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.15);

}

.nav-justified > li:first-child > a {

  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;

}

.nav-justified > li:last-child > a {

  border-bottom: 0;

  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;

}


@media (min-width: 768px) {

  .nav-justified {

    max-height: 52px;

  }

  .nav-justified > li > a {

    border-right: 1px solid #d5d5d5;

    border-left: 1px solid #fff;

  }

  .nav-justified > li:first-child > a {

    border-left: 0;

    border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;

  }

  .nav-justified > li:last-child > a {

    border-right: 0;

    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;

  }

}
```

Comment: Almost, is there a good way of creating even spacing between the buttons? It looks like they're using a table to align their elements. Can I still separate my buttons then?

Comment: Leave li items as they are and give margin (like margin: 0 20px;) to li > a links.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11787056)

Comment: @Panther Thank you, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

It will sound obvious but you can do all that with CSS. Just select the right containers and shape them however you want. So if you select li element for example you can set 200px width and they'll all be same size. And you can use simple .collapse class of bootstrap if you want to gather them under a button or use @media query and do something like:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    li {
display: block;
    }
}
```